# How do I join two named pipes into single input stream in linux

Tags: linux, shell

Using the pipes (`|`) feature in Linux I can forward chain the standard input to one or several output streams.

I can use `tee` to split the output to separate sub processes.

Is there a command to join two input streams?

How would I go about this?  How does diff work?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Personally, my favorite (requires bash and other things that are standard on most Linux distributions)

The details can depend a lot on what the two things output and how you want to merge them ...

Contents of command1 and command2 after each other in the output:

```
cat <(command1) <(command2) > outputfile
```

Or if both commands output alternate versions of the same data that you want to see side-by side (I've used this with snmpwalk; numbers on one side and MIB names on the other):

```
paste <(command1) <(command2) > outputfile
```

Or if you want to compare the output of two similar commands (say a find on two different directories)

```
diff <(command1) <(command2) > outputfile
```

Or if they're ordered outputs of some sort, merge them:

```
sort -m <(command1) <(command2) > outputfile
```

Or run both commands at once (could scramble things a bit, though):

```
cat <(command1 & command2) > outputfile
```

The <() operator sets up a named pipe (or /dev/fd) for each command, piping the output of that command into the named pipe (or /dev/fd filehandle reference) and passes the name on the commandline.  There's an equivalent with >().  You could do: `command0 | tee >(command1) >(command2) >(command3) | command4` to simultaneously send the output of one command to 4 other commands, for instance.

Comment: awesome!  i've read bash's manpage lots of time but hadn't pick that one

Comment: You can find the reference in the [advanced bash scripting guide] (http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) at the linux documentation project

Comment: i was able to prevent interleaved lines by piping through `grep --line-buffered` - handy for concurrently `grep`'ing the `tail` of multiple log files. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443704/line-buffered-cat

Answer (score 18):

You can append two steams to another with `cat`, as gorilla shows.

You can also create a FIFO, direct the output of the commands to that, then read from the FIFO with whatever other program:

```
mkfifo ~/my_fifo
command1 > ~/my_fifo &
command2 > ~/my_fifo &
command3 < ~/my_fifo
```

Particularly useful for programs that will only write or read a file, or mixing programs that only output stdout/file with one that supports only the other.

Comment: This one works on pfSense (FreeBSD) whereas the accepted answer does not.  Thank you!

Comment: How does this work in terms of preventing either files from overwriting each other's data? I'm looking for something that respects line buffering

Answer (score 13):

```
(tail -f /tmp/p1 & tail -f /tmp/p2 ) | cat > /tmp/output
```

`/tmp/p1` and `/tmp/p2` are your input pipes, while `/tmp/output` is the output.

Comment: Note: Unless both commands in side the `()` flush their output on every line (and some other obscure POSIX rules for atomicity), you could end up with some weird scrambling on the input to cat ...

Comment: Should you not be using semicolon instead of ampersand character?

Comment: this is Epic stuff

Answer (score 7):

I have created special program for this: [fdlinecombine](https://github.com/vi/fdlinecombine)

It reads multiple pipes (usually program outputs) and writes them to stdout linewise (you can also override the separator)

Comment: Works as advertized. Thank you for making it public.

Answer (score 4):

Be careful here; just catting them will end up mixing the results in ways you may not want: for instance, if they're log files you probably don't really want a line from one inserted halfway through a line from the other.  If that's okay, then

> tail -f /tmp/p1 /tmp/p2 >
> /tmp/output

will work.  If that's *not* okay, then you're going to have to do find something that will do line buffering and only output complete lines.  Syslog does this, but I'm not sure what else might.

**EDIT: optimized for unbuffered reading and named pipes:**

considering /tmp/p1 , /tmp/p2 , /tmp/p3 as named pipes, created by "mkfifo /tmp/p*N*"

> tail -q -f /tmp/p1 /tmp/p2 | awk '{print $0 > "/tmp/p3"; close("/tmp/p3"); fflush();}' &

now we can read the output named pipe "/tmp/p3" **unbuffered** by :

> tail -f /tmp/p3

there is small bug of sort, you need to "initialize" the 1st input pipe /tmp/p1 by:

> echo -n > /tmp/p1

in order to get **tail** to accept the input from 2nd pipe /tmp/p2 first and not wait until something comes to /tmp/p1 . This may not be the case unless you are sure /tmp/p1 will receive input first.

Also the -q option is needed so **tail** does not print garbage about filenames.

Comment: the more usefull will be:
**"tail -q -f /tmp/p1 /tmp/p2 | another_command"**
as it will be done line by line and with -q option it will not print any other garbage

Comment: for unbuffered file/named pipe use:

**`tail -q -f /tmp/p1 /tmp/p2 | awk '{print $0 > "/tmp/p3"; close("/tmp/p3"); fflush();}' &`**


now the /tmp/p3 can be even named pipe and you can read it by simply **`tail -f /tmp/p3`** all this is **UNBUFFERED = line by line**

there is however small bug of sort. the 1st file/named pipe needs to be initialized first in order tail will accept the output from the 2nd. so you will need to `echo -n > /tmp/p1` and than everything will work smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

A really cool command I have used for this is `tpipe`, you might need to compile because it not that common. Its really great for doing exactly what your talking about, and it's so clean I usually install it.  The man page is located here http://linux.die.net/man/1/tpipe .  The currently listed download is at this archive http://www.eurogaran.com/downloads/tpipe/ .

It's used like this,

```
## Reinject sub-pipeline stdout into standard output:
$ pipeline1 | tpipe "pipeline2" | pipeline3
```

Answer (score 1):

The best program for doing this is [`lmerge`](https://github.com/dairicksonmuli/lmerge). Unlike freihart's answer it's line-oriented so the output of the two commands won't clobber each other. Unlike other solutions it fairly merges the input so no command can dominate the output. For example:

```
$ lmerge <(yes foo) <(yes bar) | head -n 4
```

Gives output of:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```